# Jenkins URL localhost:8080 redirects me out to localhost, breaking webpage

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm having issues with the Jenkins proxy. The Jenkins container is behind my NGINX proxy. I access it at http://localhost:8000. After I log in I get kicked to http://localhost. Some links on Jenkins also does the same and removes the port which brakes the screen. I get the error on the from the title on my Manage Jenkins page and tried adding the proxy_pass URL also, but nothing works.

My NGINX conf file is like so...

```
server {
   listen       8000;
   server_name  "";

   access_log off;

   location / {

       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_pass         http://jenkins_master_1:8080;
       proxy_redirect http://jenkins_master_1:8080 http://localhost:8000;

       proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

       proxy_connect_timeout      150;
       proxy_send_timeout         100;
       proxy_read_timeout         100;

       proxy_buffer_size          8k;
       proxy_buffers              4 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;    

   }

}
```

my docker-compose.yml file is like so...

```
version: '3'

# Services are the names of each container
services:
  master:
    # Where to build the container from a Dockerfile
    build: ./jenkins-master
    # Open which ports to
    ports: 
      - "50000:50000"
    # Connecting volumes to in a container
    volumes:
      - jenkins-log:/var/log/jenkins
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    # Adding the service to a network
    networks: 
      - jenkins-net

  nginx:
    build: ./jenkins-nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks: 
      - jenkins-net

# List of volumes to create
volumes: 
  jenkins-data:
  jenkins-log:

# List of netorks to create
networks: 
  jenkins-net:
```

I'm trying to learn Docker and Jenkins and was following a tutorial, the jenkins_master_1 is from the docker-compose. Any help or guidance would be really appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. There is my solution without docker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77209893/12282542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption 1: NGINX is in front of your app, accepting connections on port 80, then passing to backend port 8080.

Assumption 2: the Jenkins application and NGINX are on the same server here.

You should be accessing it originally from port 80, not 8080 if you are using the proxy.

NGINX gets request on 80, then passes to backend 8080. From the browser you shouldn’t see the 8080 if you are using the proxy. If you are using 8080 and it’s doing something, then your going directly to app.... aka, bypassing the proxy.

So, how to start addressing it:

(1.) Navigate to http://localhost, which should go through your proxy (if it’s set up properly)

(2.) In Manage Jenkins-> Configure System -> Jenkins URL, make sure the URL is set to http://localhost

(3.) Better to use a FQDN for the server name in the NGINX configuration, then make sure Jenkins is only listening for connections on localhost in the Jenkins.xml configuration. Jenkins.xml should have listen address set to 127.0.0.1. Then external requests to that FQDN will not be able to bypass the proxy, as Jenkins will only be allowing connections from localhost (from NGINX, or you playing with the browser on the localhost).

Then, ideally, you have:
http://fqdn->NGINX listening on port 80 -> Jenkins on 127.0.0.1:8080. The user with their browser (safely outside of your server) never sees the 8080 port.

Comment: That is really helpful! Thanks Jesse. I think the reason I set the port to 8080 as my work laptop wasn't allowing me to use port 80. I'm going to get be it another go and research FQDN also :). Will update once I make it to work!

Comment: So I see my laptop is using port 80 for something and without admin, I can't stop it. Could I have the Docker image listen to say 8000, build it and have it listen like 8000:8000? Or does NGINX only listen to port 80?

Comment: Yeah I did as I explained about, Manage Jenkins error is gone, can't access jenkins through 8080, but the links still don't line up correctly. They will bring me back to localhost without the port.

Comment: High ports are usually safer to use with fewer security problems. You could set NGINX to listen on 8081 at the top of your config. Then you would go to http://localhost:8081 in your browser to access the application.

Comment: Yeah decided to go with port 8000. Everything is working except for it redirecting me to http://localhost a lot, breaking the smoothness of it. It's actually driving me mental like! Have you had that issue before yourself?

Comment: This looks helpful. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy

Comment: The proxy_redirect from your config above is missing Szczad comment below. It seems it would actually be:  
proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
proxy_redirect localhost:8080 http://jenkins_master_1:8000;

Then browse to http://jenkins_master_1:8000 in your browser.

Assumption, jenkins_master_1 is your server name.

Comment: Sigh, I've managed to fix it now. This is what fixed it...  proxy_redirect http://localhost http://localhost:8000; I then set my Manage Jenkins->Jenkins Url to http://localhost. This removed that error and stopped the linking redirecting like crazy! Omg, that was annoying. Jesse, thank you for your time. I will accept your answer as you stepped through the process with me and helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `proxy_redirect` directive in `location` block. This instructs webserver to return different 301/302 http response codes than calculated by the server itself. Sometimes the webserver is unable to properly calculate its address like in docker where the container has no information of the outside world and that the connection is proxied/forwarded.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins_master_1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://jenkins_master_1:8080 http://localhost:8080;
}
```

SRC: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Comment: Hi Szczad, Thanks for sending the link and your answer. It's weird I've added what you mentioned. Even changed the https->http just to be sure. even changed the Jenkins URL to the localhost equivalent. But still no luck. I want to try understand why it's kicking me out and will be able to host it then.

Comment: Try following the guide below. Maybe adding other X-Forwarded-* headers fix that issue. That's indeed strange, but on the other side I had quite similar issue but with standalone Jenkins deployment.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken

Comment: Yeah, that was my first port of call once I saw the error on Jenkins. I'll look over it again. Hopefully, something stands out. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Add X-Forwarded-* headers is the right solution.

Without such headers, I got a lot of errors such as I was redirected to https://jenkinsci:8080 after I set the initial password and click continue button. Many times when I visit https://jenkins.mydomain.com and click the links on the webpage, I was redirected to https://jenkinsci:8080. And https://jenkinsci:8080 can not be visited obviously. I dont't know why. Maybe tomact needs those  X-Forwarded-* headers information.

This article - [Jenkins behind an NGinX reverse proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy) is highly recommended for those who want to run jenkins behind nginx, even if both jenkins and nginx are created through docker container. And once again, you'd better add those X-Forwarded-* headers.

An example nginx vhost configuration file:

```
server {
charset utf8;

access_log   /var/log/nginx/jenkins.yourdomain.com.access_log  main;

listen       443 ssl http2;
server_name  jenkins.yourdomain.com;


ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/yourdomain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/yourdomain.com.key;
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

location / {

    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_pass   http://jenkinsci:8080; #jenkinsci is the service/container name specified in the docker-compose.yml file
}
```

}