# Configure nginx to run jenkins on specific path

Tags: .net, linux, nginx, jenkins, virtual-machine

I am new in linux world so hope my question is formulated correctly.

I have hosted my .net core app on linux vm (centos) running on localhost:5000 and have nginx set up to access it from outisde. I access this website like this http://myipaddress/

I also installed jenkins and it is running on localhost:8080 inside vm.

I want to configure nginx.config file like that so I had access to jenkins on path http://myipaddress/jenkins

nginx.config file:

```
       server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;
       location /  {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
```

I think I should add new 'location' entry to point to jenkins but not sure how to do it.
any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I am not using docker.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to configure Jenkins with a context path. You can do this by passing a launch parameter `--prefix=/jenkins`. If you are on docker you can pass it like below.

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Else you can export the following env variable.

```
export JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```

Once that's done a simple Nginx rule like below should work for you.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.ycr.com;

    location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://jenkins.ycr.com/;
        }
}
```

Comment: what should I write here if I have no domain ? 'server_name jenkins.ycr.com;'

Comment: @Vazha you can add your IP.

Comment: I added
 location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }  
but now when I navigate to myip/jenkins it redirects me to the /login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F and says 'No webpage was found for the web address'

Comment: @Vazha efore accessing through NginX make sure you can access Jenkins with the new context directly. `http://IP:8080/jenkins` all the redirected URLs should have the /jenkins context. If not you have not followed the instructions properly.

Answer (score 1):

- Docker:

```
docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

`-p 50000:50000`: will be used when you connect a slave agent, [more details](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#connecting-agents)

- Docker file:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
.......
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins"
......
EXPOSE 8080
```

- Docker compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS=--prefix=/jenkins
```

- SYS_VM_MACHINE:

  Edit jenkins config file and add `--prefix=/jenkins` to 'JENKINS_ARGS'.

  - Ubuntu/Debian => '/etc/default/jenkins'
  - Rhel/CentOS   => '/etc/sysconfig/jenkins'

```
JENKINS_ARGS="... --prefix=/jenkins"
```

Nginx config like :

```
upstream jenkins_server {
  keepalive 64; # keepalive connections
  server 127.0.0.1:8080; # jenkins ip and port
}

server {
   listen       80;
   #Add mapping in file /etc/hosts to using a HostName Instead of Ip Adress
   server_name  "my.servername.local" ;

   ...

   location ^~ /jenkins/ {
       proxy_pass         http://jenkins_server/jenkins;

       proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

       # for jenkins websocket agents
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";  

       proxy_connect_timeout      150;
       proxy_send_timeout         100;
       proxy_read_timeout         100;

       proxy_buffer_size          8k;
       proxy_buffers              4 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution after which you will get access to your jenkins via path **/jenkins**.

1. `sudo systemctl edit jenkins` and insert next:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PREFIX=/jenkins"
```

[image]

2. `sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins`
   find variable **JENKINS_ARGS** and append `--prefix=/jenkins`:
   [image]
3. go to your website nginx config.
   For me it's `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/parfenov.dev`
   Insert into your **server** block location **/jenkins** with next config:

```
location /jenkins {
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jenkins;
                proxy_read_timeout  90s;
        }
```

**/etc/nginx/proxy_params** includes:
[image]

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/parfenov.dev** will look like:
[image]

4. Don't forget to restart jenkins and nginx.

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```